# How do you setup shipping services that relate to a specific taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce

I have taxonomy reference field for each product. I have DVD,CD and e-Download.
If user purchase the e-download related products shipping charge should be free. How to add the conditions using rules module.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use Data Comparison in conditions section of rule. Where in data comparison you need set commerce-product:creator:fieldname **OPERATOR** equals and in DATA VALUE you need to select 'e-Download'. done

Comment: commerce-product:creator:field_category this token value not available in the data selector.

Comment: On which event rules work on?

Comment: Collecting shipping rates for an order this event i used it